# incorrect Ghidra decompile functions parameters

Tags: ghidra, hexrays

I am checking a binary with Ghidra, and it adds to me a lot of parameters to many functions while in IDA it decompiles it well. (I used decompiler parameter ID)

I saw someone wrote here about this problem:
https://github.com/NationalSecurityAgency/ghidra/issues/4329

Is there any way to fix it ?

Comment: As it stands -- you even referenced the ticket yourself -- there does not seem to be a way. Perhaps you also want to state the exact Ghidra version you're using so it doesn't cause confusion in the future when others find your Q&A. I'll leave this open in case someone knows a way to work around it. PS: it would also be great if you could add more detail such as an example where you contrast the outcome from Ghidra and that from the Hex-Rays decompiler plugin. PPS: IDA is a disassembler and the decompiler Hex-Rays offers is a **plugin** to it.

Comment: Are you aware of the "Edit Function Signature..." dialog?